# How to read uploaded file in post buffer without name in Rails

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webclient

How does one read a file from the post buffer in Rails, when it doesn't have a name?

My client is a c# application, which calls WebClient.UploadFile().   This POSTs a file to my server, with it's contents in the post buffer.

The kicker is, the file is not posted with a name/value pair as you would get if you put an `<input type=file name"myfile">` tag in a form on web page; it's just the file.

When i inspect the request that my controller receives, I see a tempfile as a property to Http::UploadedFile.  I've confirmed this file is the complete contents of the file my client uploaded, however but I'm not clear on how to access it via the object model..

I'm sure others have done c# WebClient.UploadFile() -> rails server.    Any hints?

Comment: Please can you display the request params comming to your controller.

Comment: Preparing to do this made me realize my own code was tripping me up.  Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, rails makes this too easy.

```
params[:file]
```

is of type `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, and appears to be a parameter rails sets up automatically in this case.  The file itself can be accessed by

```
params[:file].tempfile
```